# Spring JPA Parameter value [1000] did not match expected type [ma.mycom.myapp.domain.Client (n/a)]

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have two entities called `Appointement` and `Client`, and I would like to get all the
*appointements* of a given *client*. I am struggling with the following error message when I try to do so.

> 2022-05-24 13:30:41.685  WARN 23252 --- [  XNIO-3 task-1]
> .m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved
> [org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Parameter
> value [1000] did not match expected type [ma.mycom.myapp.domain.Client
> (n/a)]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
> Parameter value [1000] did not match expected type
> [ma.mycom.myapp.domain.Client (n/a)]]

Here are my entities:

**Client.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CLIENTS")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Client implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    //other attributes, getters, setters
    
}
```

**Appointment.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "APPOINTMRNTS")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Appointment implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;
    //other attributes

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_CLIENT")
    private Client client;

   //getters, setters
    
}
```

**Controller, and how I call the query:**

```
List<Appointement> clientAppointements = appointementRepository.findAllByClient(idClient);
```

**Here is the query used in `AppointementRepository.java` (I guess it's the source of the problem)**

```
@Query(
        name = "SELECT pe.* FROM APPOINTEMENTS pe INNER JOIN CLIENTS e ON pe.ID_CLIENT = e.ID WHERE e.id = ?1",
        nativeQuery = true
    )
List<Appointement> findAllByClient(Long idClient);
```

Comment: Ditch `@Query` rename method to `findAllByClientId`, restart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Appointment` class does not have a field called "client id" of any sort, it is only aware of the `Client` entity it has.

<s>In your JPA repository methods, you can only use the existing fields of an entity.</s>

Two of the most standard ways you can fix this are:

### 1- Adding `Appointment` field to the `Client` side of the relationship to make it bidirectional (I recommend this personally). Your `Client` entity will look like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CLIENTS")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_WRITE)
public class Client implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "client", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    List<Appointment> appointments;

    //other attributes, getters, setters
   
}
```

Then you can simply get appointments by fetching a `Client` object, then simply accessing its `appointments` field.

```
List<Appointement> clientAppointements = clientRepository.findClientByField(field)
.getAppointments();
```

or you can even get appointments of a client in repository methods:

```
// in your appointment repository

@Query(value = "SELECT c.appointments FROM Client c WHERE c.id = :cId")
List<Appointment> getAppointmentsById(Long cId);
```

### 2- If you don't want to make the relationship bidirectional, you should fetch the `Client` object before searching it with the `Appointment` repository methods.

```
// in your appointment repository
List<Appointment> findByClient(Client client);

// then you can fetch it anywhere
Client client = clientRepository.findById(cliendId);
List<Appointment> clientAppointments = appointmentRepository.findByClient(client);
```